# Ayuda, como sacar elementos de un datalist en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web en ASP.Net, y tengo un datalist que contiene varios elementos entre ellos un label.

Ese label tiene un dato que lo obtengo de una base de datos en SQL pero, al momento de hacer el llamado para obtener los datos de ese label, no me aparece su identificador, porque está dentro del Datalist.

Quiero saber cómo podría buscar ese label u obtener la información que tiene.

```html
 <asp:DataList ID="dtlEventos" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="view view-first">
            <asp:Image ID="ImgEventos" runat="server" style="width:auto;" CssClass="centered img-responsive" Height="100%" ImageUrl='<%# "/Imagenes/" + Eval("foto") %>' />
            <div class="mask">
                <h2><asp:Label ID="blbNomEvento" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nom_evento") %>' ></asp:Label></h2>

                <br>
                <br></br>
                <asp:Button ID="btnViewmore" runat="server" OnClick="btnViewmore_Click" Text="Ver más" />
                </br>
            </div>                            
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edites la pregunta con código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Exactamente, por favor comparte el código con el que has avanzado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo visto logre entender tu pregunta, este es el código que vas a agregar del lado del servidor osea en C#:

`protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)sender;
            Panel Panel = (Panel)ib.Parent;
            DataListItem Fila = (DataListItem)Panel.Parent;
            Label Id = (Label)Fila.Controls[1];
            Session["idServicio"] = Id.Text;
            Response.Redirect("DetalleProducto.aspx"); 
        }`

En mi caso yo utilice un ImageButton para mandar a mi siguiente página en tu caso veo que utilizas un Button para capturara los datos.
en la linea `Label Id = (Label)Fila.Controls[1];` checa porque en mi código lo puse al principio de todos los elementos asp.net espero ayudar.